# How do I run a script as sudo at boot time on Ubuntu 18.04 Server?

Tags: 18.04, scripts

How do I run a script as sudo at boot time?

I need to run `ethtool --offload <net> rx off` to disable the annoying jme udp checksum error message.

Comment: why do you believe you would need sudo at boot time?

Comment: @Rinzwind probably because ethtool needs root to run.  SystemD unit as root is the best approach

Comment: "as sudo" - you mean "as `root` (the all-powerful user with `$UID=0`)". `sudo` is a tool for allowing a regular user to run a command as `root`. "at boot" - everything involved with system startup runs as `root`

Comment: @waltinator: except things that drop privileges; e.g. you can have your system start up an X server + user session for a certain user.  But running `ethtool` via sudo from something that had dropped privileges (like the wording of this question suggest) would be a really bad idea vs. sticking it in `/etc/rc.local` or any more "modern" way to get things run as root during boot.

Answer (score 35):

You can create a systemd service.

Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/ethtool.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=ethtool script

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/yourscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And script `/path/to/yourscript.sh` (don't forget to `chmod +x` it)

```
#!/bin/bash
ethtool --offload <net> rx off
```

Enable your service

```
systemctl enable ethtool
```

It will run on boot as root.

Comment: If @deimos excellent answer was helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate knowing that the answer works as expected.

Comment: `sudo systemctl start ethtool` to start the service immediately. `systemctl status ehttool` to display status (running, enabled and log). Learn more with `man systemctl`

Answer (score 5):

Put your commands in /etc/rc.local
or create that file if it does not exist:

```
 touch /etc/rc.local
 chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

All these actions have to be done as root.

Comment: Can we put non-root commands in `rc.local`?

Comment: By now I read almost everywhere in recent articles that systemd is the way to go, and `/etc/rc.local` is to be seen as legacy measure.