# Run command at reboot

Tags: battery, reboot

I would like to preserve the battery on my laptop by limiting how much it gets charged.

There is a file (*/sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit*) with a value of *100*.
I can run command

```
echo '80' | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit
```

I have to run this command at every reboot.

I have tried adding it via crontab -e but it doesn't work.

How do I get this command to run automatically at every reboot?

### Additional information posted as an answer

thanks for the reply.

This works:

```
@reboot echo 80 > /home/myuser/test.txt
```

Tried and failed all the following:

```
@reboot echo 80 > /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit
@reboot sudo echo 80 > /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit
@reboot sleep 60 && echo 80 > /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit
@reboot sleep 60 && sudo echo 80 > /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit
```

At least the command is being attempted.
`journalctl -b  | grep echo` returns:

```
CRON[1041]: (myuser) CMD (sudo echo 80 > /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit)
CRON[1045]: (myuser) CMD (sleep 60 && sudo echo 80 > /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit)
```

Comment: Converting something that works in a terminal to something that works in cron can be problematic. You haven’t provided any information about the errors that are arising. You could try something like `echo 80 > /home/myuser/test.txt` in your cron job to confirm cron is working. You don’t need the tee command because cron doesn’t output to STDOUT. You could try `sudo echo 80 > /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/battery_care_limit` and trouble shoot from there

Comment: @PonJar Redirection in the shell happen before the execution of the command so not affected by `sudo` and nothing will be written to the file after `>` that way as it need elevated permissions ... Please see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: another option can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151080/how-do-i-run-a-script-as-sudo-at-boot-time-on-ubuntu-18-04-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a script as sudo at boot time on Ubuntu 18.04 Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151080/how-do-i-run-a-script-as-sudo-at-boot-time-on-ubuntu-18-04-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` has no significance in crontab entries.

If you need to run a cron job with elevated permissions(*like `sudo` does*), then add an entry for it to the root's crontab using:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Which runs the jobs as root instead of just:

```
crontab -e
```

Which runs the job as your user.

Comment: Thanks Raffa, That worked :) Which of these two is the best practice for delaying the cron job? `@reboot sleep 10; echo 80 > ...` or `@reboot sleep 10 && echo 80 > ...`

Comment: Both might work but I would go with `@reboot sleep 10 && echo 80 > ...` as this will execute the second command only if the first command succeeds ... And please read about how this site works [here](https://askubuntu.com/help) ... You are adding answers that should be either edits to your question or comments to other people's answers ... People here like things to be tidy and you're making them unhappy :-D ... So please leave only your question and delete your answers and accept my answer if it works for you so future readers will find the right solution easily.